# Flask organize marshmallow schemas

Tags: python, flask, serialization, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm developing API in `Flask framework`, and is getting bigger. For now I have dozens of `sqlalchemy` models and even more `Marshmallow` CRUD schemas.

Things are going a bit messy and hard to maintain, mainly with schemas, so I have questions about best way to organize whole structure in larger Flask aplication, and what's serialize approach better to maintain in endpoints that have:

- nested json response

```
/v0/user/all

{ 
   "data":{ 
      "id":1,
      "name":"foo",
      "phone":"927487286",
      "courses":[ 
         { 
            "id":12,
            "name":"Math",
            "place":{ 
               "id":1,
               "location":"Foo Street"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

- can use schemas that were used in different endpoint, but with different fields

```
/v0/courses/{id}

{ 
   "data":{ 
      "id":12,
      "name":"Math",
      "place":{ 
         "location":"Foo Street"
      }
   }
}
```

I was thinking about implementing method `to_dict` in my models, but those can be also hard to maintain when it comes to nested in another serializers.

Any advice?

Comment: Please update your question to contain your current directory structure, an example of your model and current serializer you have in place.

Answer (score 0):

The point of marshmallow is to avoid `to_dict` methods in objects by delegating the view responsibility to Schemas. See [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/sloria/marshmallow-for-data-validation-and-serialization?slide=7) by Steven Loria (marshmallow author).

If your API schemas are close to your DB structure, you can limit duplication by using [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io) to generate the API Schemas automatically from the models.

If the API Schemas differ too much form the model, then you may be better off building a Schema from scratch for each resource. You could still use the [field_for](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#overriding-generated-fields) method from marshmallow-sqlalchemy to avoid duplicating model types and validators.